# Mock extension function in kotlin-stdlib

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mocking, extension-methods, mockk

I have a method to download content from streaming end point. I want to write unit test this method. What I faced a problem is I need to mock kotlin extension method `file.outputStream()` but I can't mock
`outputStream()` which is defined in  `kotlin-stdlib` `FileReadWrite` File as like below

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun File.outputStream(): FileOutputStream {
    return FileOutputStream(this)
}
```

My download method is like below

```
override fun download(url: String, targetFile: File): Single<File> {
    return Single.fromCallable {
            fileDownloadApi
            .downloadFile(url)
            .execute()
            .body()?.byteStream()?.use { input ->
                targetFile.outputStream().use { output ->
                    FileUtil.copyFile(input, output)
                    return@fromCallable targetFile
                }
            }
        targetFile
    }
}
```

I need to mock this part `targetFile.outputStream()` .
I am passing mock `targetFile`

My test code is like bolow

```
val mockFileOutputStream = mockk<FileOutputStream>()
val mockTargetFile = mockk<File>()
mockkStatic("kotlin.io.FilesKt")  // declares as JvmName @file:JvmName("FilesKt")
every { File("abc").outputStream() } returns mockFileOutputStream

service.download("", mockTargetFile)
    .subscribe(testObserver)
```

I mocked `file.outputStream()` like [official doc](https://mockk.io/#extension-functions) suggested but getting error

> io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock

for line `every { File("abc").outputStream() } returns mockFileOutputStream`

I can't figureout what i'm missing. Please help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the extension function is `inline`. This means that when you call it, there is no actual call to the extension method declared in `FilesKt`. Instead, the compiler generates code that directly calls the constructor of `FileOutputStream`, since that is the implementation of `outputStream`.

So what you should be mocking is the constructor of `FileOutputStream`, not `FilesKt`.

For example,

```
mockkConstructor(FileOutputStream::class) {
    // write the mocks that you would have written for mockFileOutputStream here
    every { anyConstructed<FileOutputStream>().write(...) } just runs
    // and you don't need mockFileOutputStream anymore
}
```

Comment: This not worked for mock File. Only worked when pass file in download method with `File("abc)` . Mock file needs lot of method mocking. :(

Comment: any way I can use mocked file?

Comment: @AbuYousuf What exactly do you mean by "not worked"? Please describe how the code behaved. Anyway, I don't think you need the mocked `File` anymore? The second argument for `download` is practically ignored. If you really need it, try mocking `File`'s constructor too. Also, consider posting a new question.

Comment: Yes i used newly created `File.` For mocked file FileOutputStream constructor call different method on File,  need to mock those method too.

Comment: @AbuYousuf Why do you insist on using a mocked file? Why not use a real file? It's very easy to create temporary files for testing using `File.createTempFile`. If you do that, you wouldn't even need to mock the `FileOutputStream` constructor. I would suggest asking a new question explaining what you are trying to test.

Comment: I am using real file for unit test. I was thinking mocked file would give me more control or I can just ignore outside code execution from my test class. Anyway my issue solved with real file. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Another think I thought creating real file will not work thats why thinking about mocking file